# Freescale lpuart Linux driver, how to invert RTS polarity?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am working on bringing up Linux on a prototype based around a Freescale Vybrid SoC. One of the embedded UARTS therein is used to drive an external line driver which must be switched on and off either side of a burst of data.

I am using the UART's RTS output to perform this gating, but the polarity of this signal is by default inverted from what I require for my external circuit. The Freescale UART does have a flag in one of the control registers to invert this signal in hardware, but there does not appear to be a way to tell the Linux lpuart driver to modify it.

I considered:

- Subverting the driver's existing CRTSCTS flag to additionally set/reset this hardware bit and use e.g. stty to modify it from userspace. (In my application, I do not currently require a non-inverted RTS.)
- Making a copy of the lpuart driver which always initialises this special control bit and call it something else, modifying this one uart in my dt file accordingly.
- Setting the control bit from userspace by e.g. writing /dev/mem.

But none of these seems like a good solution to me. What is the correct way?

Comment: Consider adding a new ioctl() to the existing driver to either toggle this output, or to reconfigure the driver to manipulate this output as required.  RS-485 also uses RTS to perform a "gating" for half-duplex.  Only a few Linux serial port drivers support it, but you could use them as examples.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the tip. I am indeed driving a multidrop bus similar to rs-485. I added an initialiser function to the existing RS485 structure and added a new device tree property to specify that the RTS should be inverted (SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND) in Linux parlance. I don't fully understand why a dt binding for this particular flag doesn't already exist.